# PHP json encode to JS not getting full HTML

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

For some reason when I use `json_encode` and then `JSON.parse` to grab the array in JS - HTML strings are only getting the closing tag of the string. So for instance:

```
$php_array = array (
    "title" => "this is a <strong>title</strong>",
    "text" => "<p>this is some text</p>"
)
<div id="data"><?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?></div>
```

Then in JS:

```
const someArray = $('#data').text();
const data = JSON.parse(someArray);
```

The output looks like:

```
0:
  title: "this is a title</strong>",
  text: "this is some text</p>"
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You are outputting HTML and the browser is interpreting it as such.

Change this line:

```
<div id="data"><?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?></div>
```

To this:

```
<script> var data = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>; </script>
```

Comment: You should include a `;` at the end of the `?>` to signal javascript that this element is complete. See [phpplayground here](https://www.tehplayground.com/mkzJ29FbB4DVjce0). (Removing the semicolon does break the script).

Comment: @FrankerZ Done.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `htmlspecialchars()` to the specific HTML items fixed this.